# How can I collect and format filename, size and extension of directory contents in bash?

Tags: bash

I am looking to output a list of contents formatted by size, type of each file and the file name without the extension.

I've tried using ls grep and awk but to no avail. I'm not sure how else this could be done, could someone help me?

I'm looking for the output to show as below;

```
   Filename        FileSize      Extension
   Filename        FileSize      Extension
   Filename        FileSize      Extension
   Filename        FileSize      Extension
```

and so on.

Comment: at least show the approximate expected result, show how it should look

Comment: Sorry So I'm expecting the output to be something like this.                                       filename    filesize   filetype

Comment: `filetype` is cosidered as *extension*?

Comment: And What have you tried? This Q will likely be voted closed because of "asking for a tutorial" OR "too broad". Your Q needs to show specific code, with actual sample inputs, expected outputs, error messages and your thoughts about how you think it should work, v.s. how it is currently working. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. (I didn't downvote). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `ls` here (and, in fact, good reason not to use it; see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)).

As native bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in *; do                 # iterate over contents of current directory
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue    # skip things that aren't files
  size=$(wc -c <"$file")          # collect size
  # ...and actually format and print metadata
  printf '%20q %20s %q\n' "${file%.*}" "$size" "${file##*.}"
done
```

Here, `%q` is used to ensure that even names with nonprintable components are formatted unambiguously (so you can tell the difference between a name with spaces and a name with tabs, for example).